# get utx scriptPubKey to become an object

Tags: script, utxo

I'm using this python script https://github.com/sebicas/bitcoin-sniffer

When I see a utx I look at each output and find the `scriptPubKey`

I expected to see something like

```
"scriptPubKey": {
   "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 2544bedede7298fe7cedb3fcd0eb5fa73729eb64 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
   "hex": "76a9142544bedede7298fe7cedb3fcd0eb5fa73729eb6488ac",
   "reqSigs": 1,
   "type": "pubkeyhash",
   "addresses": [
                    "14Q4MdFGqFbP9WPzz3AXjsdxZC68rCQjj1"
                    ]
                }
```

but instead I see

```
"scriptPubKey":v��_/{�/k>//��7`HH��
```

Is it binary or encoded or encrypted??

How do I get the information I need from the utx?

**I am looking to get asm and hex**

Comment: I don't know much about python, but I've had similar issues with other libs and the solution was to declare it a string.

Comment: I tried `str(scriptPubKey)` and `v��_/{�/k>//��7`HH��` is exactly what it looks like